# Redirect all errors to 404 page

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

How can I force TYPO3 to display 404 page instead of displaying technical errors?

Example if TYPO3 can not resolve given url to property I am getting following error:

```
Oops, an error occurred!
Exception while property mapping at property path "": The identity 
property "dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg" is no UID.
More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

I already tried to resolve it by configuring

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = 
'USER_FUNCTION:.....';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageUnavailable_handling'] = 
 'USER_FUNCTION:.....';
```

but this does not seem to have any effect on those types of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried from here

[image: It will better if you set if from install tool]

[image: set this variable from install tool :pageUnavailable_handling]

I hope this will help you!!

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my post - I alredy tried to configure pageNotFound_handling and pageUnavailable_handling but that seems not to catch those errors.

Comment: have you set pageNotFound handling in "site configuration"?